# Error: BrokenCount >0 Ubuntu Error PLEASE HELP

Tags: 18.04, dpkg, software-center, gnome-terminal

Currently using Ubuntu 18.04.4 Bionic Beaver for my desktop computer. In the top right corner I received a message stating 'Error: BrokenCount >0' This usually means that your installed packages have met unmet dependencies

I tried to update my software and this comes

Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f
Transaction failed: The package system is broken
 The following packages have unmet dependencies

libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37: Depends: libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18 (= 2.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 2.28.1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 is installed
                      Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:7) but 1:8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
                      Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.53.1) but 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.6 is installed
                      Depends: libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.21.4) but 3.22.30-1ubuntu4 is installed
                      Depends: libicu60 (>= 60.1-1~) but 60.2-3ubuntu3.1 is installed
                      Depends: libjpeg8 (>= 8c) but 8c-2ubuntu8 is installed
                      Depends: libsoup2.4-1 (>= 2.58.2) but 2.62.1-1ubuntu0.4 is installed
                      Depends: libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.7.15) but 3.22.0-1ubuntu0.3 is installed
                      Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04 is installed
                      Depends: libtasn1-6 (>= 4.12) but 4.13-2 is installed
                      Depends: libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.3-1) but 1:0.4.4-2 is installed
                      Depends: libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1) but 1:1.1.4-3 is installed
                      Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.0) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-0ubuntu2 is installed

I ran

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and everything is fine, i proceed to run `sudo apt-get -f install`

and i get this error:

```
(Reading database ... 166567 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18_2.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18:amd64 (2.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) over (2.28.1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: compressed data is corrupt
dpkg-deb: error: <decompress> subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18_2.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18.16.5' to '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18.16.5.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18_2.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can someone please advise? I am very new and would just like to remove whatever is causing this problem from my computer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1) Did you run _sudo apt-get -f install_ to fix broken packages? 2) If not, why? 3) Which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & 4) which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output indicates a corrupted package.

In fact, your output tells you exactly which package.

Delete the corrupt package:

```
    sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0-18_2.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1_amd64.deb
```

Then run `sudo apt install -f` again.